# When I delete a shortcut folder on my desktop in Win 7, do I actually delete the real folder?

Tags: windows

Let's say that I have a folder here `C:\Music`

and I right click on this folder and choose create a shortcut on desktop

Now, I have a shortcut `Music` on my desktop.

My question is if I delete the shortcut do I delete the folder and files in the real location `C:\Music`?

Because If I delete a file inside this folder this file is gone also in the real location.

An if it's possible could you tell me where in Win 7 can I adjust these settings to delete or not delete the real folder and all folders and files inside etc.

Comment: Just a note on the bit about deleting a file inside the folder you have a shortcut to; the folder shortcut takes you to the actual folder, so anything you do in there is happening to the real contents, not some copy tied to the folder shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When you delete the short cut, the original file or folder is not deleted

Comment: Could I change this behavior in Windows 7? If yes, where could I set this up? Let's say I would like to set it up to delete the original folder too when deleting the shortcut folder. Where is this possible to set?

Comment: I don't thin this can be changed. If you want to delete the original folder, just delete that, although the short cut will remain. However the shortcut will then not point to anything and will give an error message.

Comment: @Derfder - This behavior cannot be changed.  If you open the shortcut to a folder, the window that is opened, is actual folder.  Likewise when you run a shortcut to an .exe that .exe file is ran.

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut is simply a file containing a link to the target.

As Xavierjazz states, the original, target, file isn't deleted if you delete the shortcut - all that happens is that you delete the shortcut file.

There is no way to change this behaviour.  All you can do is use the shortcut to take you to the target and delete it from there.